# Switch statement : get the same result but with less code

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the impression that this script can be rewritten in a shorter way but I can not figure out how .
Is there a shorter way to do this ?

```
switch($n){
            case 1:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                break;
            case 2:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                break;
            case 3:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                break;
            case 4:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                break;
            case 5:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                break;
            case 6:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
                break;
            case 7:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
                $eta7 = $_POST['eta_7'];
                break;
            case 8:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
                $eta7 = $_POST['eta_7'];
                $eta8 = $_POST['eta_8'];
                break;
            case 9:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
                $eta7 = $_POST['eta_7'];
                $eta8 = $_POST['eta_8'];
                $eta9 = $_POST['eta_9'];
                break;
            case 10:
                $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
                $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
                $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
                $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
                $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
                $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
                $eta7 = $_POST['eta_7'];
                $eta8 = $_POST['eta_8'];
                $eta9 = $_POST['eta_9'];
                $eta10 = $_POST['eta_10'];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

The name reflects the value of the variable $ _POST received .

Using the code posted by @Don't Panic I need to update and to insert the values ​​of variables inside an existing array.

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $n_bambini; $i++) {
        ${"eta$i"} = $_POST["eta_$i"];
        $_SESSION['dati_cerca_vacanza'] = ["eta$i"=>${"eta$i"}];
    }
```

The array already exists in this format :

```
$_SESSION['dati_cerca_vacanza']= ['citta'=>$citta, 'tipo_vacanza'=>$tipo_vacanza, 'lingua'=>$lingua, 'data_arrivo'=>$data_arrivo, 'data_partenza'=>$data_partenza, 'n_adulti'=>$n_adulti, 'n_bambini'=>$n_bambini];
```

Because it does not work?

Comment: Are you just looking to save lines of code?

Comment: @THarris76 Yes...

Comment: Define the biggest possible case once inside an array and slice that array according to the switch condition.

Comment: @arkascha ....some examples

Comment: An example for an array? _Why_?!?

Comment: @arkascha You were you referring to the example of 'Don't Panic'?

Comment: @LuigiSpezia I don't think so. Mine does it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with variable variables:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $n; $i++) { 
    ${"eta$i"} = $_POST["eta_$i"];
}
```

The `${"eta$i"}` creates your various `$eta1`, `$eta2`, etc. variable names and `$_POST["eta_$i"]` gets the corresponding values from `$_POST`.

---

Regarding your edit, if you want to append these values to that session key, instead of this

```
$_SESSION['dati_cerca_vacanza'] = ["eta$i"=>${"eta$i"}];
```

You can use this

```
$_SESSION['dati_cerca_vacanza']["eta$i"] = $_POST["eta_$i"];
```

The way you're doing it would replace the entire contents of `$_SESSION['dati_cerca_vacanza']` with each iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that, but if you explain a bit more, I may be able to help.

Comment: I am trying to use your code, but I have a problem when I try to add a couple key value to an existing array

Comment: I can not write the code in the comments ! you can insert blocks of code in the comments?

Comment: I edited the question by adding details . Could you help me? thank you

Comment: Thanks ... you are great! I had already tried this form and was not working .
But thanks to your answer I have seen good code I had written and actually the array $ _SESSION [ ' dati_cerca_vacanza ' ], when I performed your code, did not exist and therefore would be overwritten !
Thank you so much! Now I have marked your name among my masters !!!! :-P

Answer (score 2):

You can invert the options like this

```
switch($n){
        case 10:
            $eta10 = $_POST['eta_10'];
        case 9:
            $eta9 = $_POST['eta_9'];
        case 8:
            $eta8 = $_POST['eta_8'];
        case 7:
            $eta7 = $_POST['eta_7'];
        case 6:
            $eta6 = $_POST['eta_6'];
        case 5:
            $eta5 = $_POST['eta_5'];
        case 4:
            $eta4 = $_POST['eta_4'];
        case 3:
            $eta3 = $_POST['eta_3'];
        case 2:
            $eta2 = $_POST['eta_2'];
        case 1:
            $eta1 = $_POST['eta_1'];
   }
```

Note there is no `break` inside the cases, so, if `$n == 10`... all the cases below are executed

Answer (score 0):

Why using so many values when you can use an array ?

```
$eta = array_values($_POST['eta']);
```

Just make sure you make your input field go into an eta array

Comment: I must highlight the age of < n > kids ... So I need to know the age of each child ..
5 children will all have different ages for example
Son 1 ( eta_1 )
Son 2 ( eta_2 )
etc..